# how can i config Menu Type: Category Articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, category

I bought a theme for my joomla webpage "joomla 3.6.5". This template uses very handy feature: all articles belonging to a category displayed vertical in a row with an navigation button at the bottom of the list. Tried to copy this layout on anothe Website i can not find the Munu Item Typ: "Category Articles" (Outputs articles from the specified category). How is this[image] Menu item type configured?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question means. Both the menu item type "category articles" and "gallery view" are not default Joomla menu items types.  Hence they must be added by something else - if they are integrated with a theme then it is unlikely that you can get exactly the same layout on another site without rebuilding the layout with your own custom layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look in the html-folder in your bought template and try to copy the files there and try to adjust them to your own layout then.

Here's a link where you can see how to add a custom blog layout, it should help to analyze the bought templates structure, so you maybe can change it for your needs.
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/custom-category-layout/